# How to parse python b' string containing dict

Tags: python

I got below stated output when I queried **hgetall** to **redis** from a **python3** script.

```
data = {
    b'category': b'0',
    b'title': b'1',
    b'display': b'1,2',
    b'type': b'1',
    b'secret': b'this_is_a_salt_key',
    b'client': b'5'}
```

it was of type **dict**.

When I tried to get "category" like

```
>>> data['category']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'category'
```

Upon reading I tried this way

```
import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: {b'category': b'0', b'title': b'1', b'display': b'1,2', b'type': b'1', b'secret': b'this_is_a_salt_key', b'client': b'5'}
```

also tried using json.dumps. but could not understand the real problem.

Please help me to parse the output and get the desired result.

Comment: b'category'.decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 12):

This is not JSON, so there is no point trying to parse it. It is a dictionary, which just happens to have keys which are byte strings. So you simply need to use byte strings to access the values:

```
data[b'category']
```

Comment: Ok.. understood, I've checked the type of b'category I got it as class bytes., but how to convert each key and value to string? so that I could apply some manipulations on some values.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the `b` in front of the key value since it is a byte string:

```
data[b'category']
```

If you want to turn the byte strings into normal strings you could do:

```
data = {b'category': b'0', b'title': b'1', b'display': b'1,2', b'type': b'1', b'secret': b'this_is_a_salt_key', b'client': b'5'}

newData = {str(key): str(value) for (key, value) in data.items()}

print newData
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 data = {key.decode('utf-8'): value.decode('utf-8') for (key, value) in c.items()}
 >>> data
 {'category': '0', 'title': '1', 'display': '1,2', 'type': '1', 'secret': 'this_is_a_salt_key', 'client': '5'}
>>> data['display']
'1,2'
>>> data['display'].split(",")
['1', '2']
```

this was my desired output.. thanks to all.

Comment: Hey man thank you for update the answer. You help me a lot.
You should apply the check mark to this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a big nested dict, this works for me:
eval(str(b_string_dict).replace("b'", "'"))