# flask application: trying to jsonify a dictionary

Tags: python, flask, redis

**Background Info**

I'm trying to write my first flask / python REST API.  So far, I have a GET that connects to a redis database and tries to convert a dictionary to json... and then return those results.

**Problem**

When I try to call jsonify on my dict object, it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/widgets/widgets.py", line 51, in get_profile
    return jsonify(res_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 263, in jsonify
    (dumps(data, indent=indent, separators=separators), '\n'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 123, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 430, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 376, in _iterencode_dict
    raise TypeError("key " + repr(key) + " is not a string")
TypeError: key b'email1' is not a string
```

The code looks like this:

```
 20 def get_db_profile(mailbox):
 21     """ connects to redis and queries for profile """
 22     try:
 23         my_redis = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
 24         response = my_redis.hgetall(55555)
 25         logging.info(response.keys())
 26         logging.info(response.items())
 27         #response = '123455555'
 28         return response
 29     except Exception as ex:
 30         return "Error:", ex

47 @application.route("/widgets/api/<int:mailbox>", methods=['GET'])
48 def get_profile(mailbox):
49     res_dict = get_db_profile(mailbox)
50 #    return application.response_class(jsonify(res_dict), content_type='application/json')
51     return jsonify(res_dict)
52 #    return '12345'
53
```

I added some logging as you can see on line 25 to see what the keys() look like.  this is what I see in the log file:

```
lab-1:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/widgets# cat /tmp/widgets.log
root - INFO - dict_keys([b'email1', b'email2'])
```

**REDIS Data**

This is how I created the redis data:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[5]> hmset 55555 email1 johndoe@hotmail.com email2 jd@yahoo.com
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[5]>
```

**Questions**

Should i be able to convert from dict object to json string? 
What is the 'b' in the log files?

```
lab-1:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/widgets# cat /tmp/widgets.log
root - INFO - dict_keys([b'email1', b'email2'])
root - INFO - dict_items([(b'email1', b'johndoe@hotmail.com'), (b'email2', b'jd@yahoo.com')])
```

How do I send back a proper JSON response?

**EDIT 1**

I found this question/answer: [How to parse python b' string containing dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523354/how-to-parse-python-b-string-containing-dict)
and based on that I tried to change my logic to look like this:

```
47 @application.route("/pvmailprofiles/api/<int:mailbox>", methods=['GET'])
48 def get_profile(mailbox):
49     res_dict = get_db_profile(mailbox)
50 #    return application.response_class(jsonify(res_dict), content_type='application/json')
51     #return jsonify(res_dict)
52     return res_dict[b'email1']
53 #    return '12345'
54
```

Line 52 - you can see that as a test I've hardcoded the 'b' and then the key name.  And it works - it returns the specific email address. 
But I need to find a way to "just" convert everything to json and return to callee.

Comment: You don't have a dictionary response. `res_dict = get_db_profile(mailbox)` is presumably throwing a `NameError`. This is clear from `TypeError: Object of type 'NameError' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: my bad.  i pasted the wrong error.  updating question.  thanks for your patience.

Comment: Question has been updated.  Pasted the right error message.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first importing json like so

```
import json
```

and then doing

```
json.dumps(myDict)
```

and then to load it again if needed.

```
json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: I have imported json library. I think it would have bombed with an error message if I hadn't, right?  but I didn't know about .dumps() and .loads().  Will google and see what I find / what they do.  Thanks.

Comment: json.dumps cannot be used the way you suggest above... at least not in my case.  It returns AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'decode' error.

Comment: The issue then seems to be in your object. Your object is a TypeError it would seem, any idea why it may come up that way?

Any regular dict can have the json.dumps method used on it, if you get my meaning.